# Rails 3.2 - Bootstrap 2.1 - Bootstrap SASS - Missing Styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting an old project out of the drawer to update some things.  I installed all the rails items on my mac, and pulled the source down from github.  I ran bundle install.  However no CSS is showing up at all in my pages when I run the server.  Is there a bootstrap initialization command I am forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

It was some cached assets, I cleared the local assets, and re-ran bundle isntall.